# check support of Universal TUN/TAP Device on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, kernel, tunnel

I am trying to setup Appgate Ip tunneling driver on my ubuntu 12.04 by following appgate instructions listed below:

### Installation, Linux

Make sure the kernel has support for the Universal TUN/TAP device driver,
  and then log in as root and create a new directory somewhere, and 
  copy the files

```
 ag_iptd
 add_route
 add_gw_route
 add_hosts_entry
 ag_iptd
 clean_hosts_file
 del_route
 del_gw_route
 del_hosts_entry
 interface_down
 interface_up
 remove_dns_server
 set_dns_server
 fix_localhost
```

into that directory. Then start the IPTD daemon by doing

```
 modprobe tun
 <directory-somewhere>/ag_iptd
```

There is also an init script 'ag_iptd.init' that can be installed
  to automatically start the IPTD daemon every time the OS is loaded.Please check the documentation of your Linux distribution on howto do this.

---

so is there any way to checkif my ubuntu 12.04 kernel has support for the Universal TUN/TAP device driver? and how to do so?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tun/tap` driver is standard in the generic 12.04 kernel: to check, enter

```
grep tun /var/log/kern.log
```

which will return

```
kernel: [2.317151] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
kernel: [2.317153] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
```

I have recently tried a VPN and set it up by installing `openvpn` and specifying the settings, etc, and the tun/tap IP tunnelling driver is used automatically. By default the `network-manager` log will go to `/var/log/syslog`, so that will contain information about when your network connection is up or when it changes, say when you connect to a VPN. That log will have IP and DNS information about the new connection and whether it is using the tun/tap driver.

Comment: Yes, I tried `modprobe tun`and didn't return any value. Doing this test i see that tun module is loaded. My problem was running openvpn w/o root. Thanks.